# Post Only text message on facebook from android application

Tags: android, facebook

sorry for the duplicate question may be but i am really faced problem with Facebook in android application , i want post only message on Facebook wall , i am able to post image with text but i want to post only text please tell me where i am wrong here is my code

This is working code for Image +Text

```
public void postImageonWall() {
    Log.i("Alok", "Test");
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    // Inflate Edit text for Facebook Message

    params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
    params.putString("app_id", mAPP_ID); // I've tried with/without this,
                                            // same result
    String message1 = "Test here ";
    params.putString("message", message1);

    // int r = jj - 1;
    //
    // Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/D&P post/postimage" + r
    // + ".jpg");

    // Get image from drawable
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory
            .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
    Log.i("Bitmap Image is here", "Bitmap" + b);
    if (b != null) {
        Log.i("Bitmap", "value");
    } else {
        Log.i("Bitmap", "null");
    }

    byte[] data = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    data = baos.toByteArray();
    if (data != null) {
        params.putByteArray("picture", data);
        Log.i("final", "value" + message);
        params.putString("caption", message);
        Log.e("PHOTOUPLOAD", "Attemping an upload...");

        AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new               AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
        mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST",
                new SampleUploadListener(), null);
        Log.e("PHOTOUPLOAD", "Attemping an upload...");
    }

}
```

Here is Simple click listner :-

public class SampleUploadListener extends BaseRequestListener {

```
    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        try {

            Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Response: " + response.toString());
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            final String src = json.getString("src");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
    }

    public void onComplete(String response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onIOException(IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

please some one tell me where i made change according to requirement .

Comment: simply remove ` params.putByteArray("picture", data);` this line and the corresponding code for it.

Comment: I have already tested but not working

Comment: are u doing  fb login first by any chance or directly calling this piece of code

Answer (score 0):

Try this Method

```
public void postToWall(String message) {
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", message);

// Uses the Facebook Graph API
try {
    facebook.request("/me/feed", params, "POST");
    this.finish();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: please try above method to post on FB wall

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following.It worked for all my projects,

```
private void postToFacebook(String review) {
        mProgress.setMessage("Posting ...");
        mProgress.show();
        AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncFbRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", title);
        params.putString("link", link);
        mAsyncFbRunner.request("me/feed", params, "POST",
                new WallPostListener());

    }
        private Handler mRunOnUi = new Handler();
    private final class WallPostListener extends BaseRequestListener {
        public void onComplete(final String response) {
            mRunOnUi.post(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    mProgress.cancel();
                    Toast.makeText(SVG_View.this,
                            "Posted to Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

        }

    }
```

Comment: are you doing fb  login   first ,then calling this  piece of code, i want to post  messasge using fb sdk 3.0,but unsuccessful